# How do I update the code of my java game with github

Tags: java, github

I was following a tutorial on youtube on how to update a java game with github but he only went as far as to tell how to update resources so I guess what I'm asking is is it the same method to update the .class files as the resources.  Please go easy on me if I did a dumb and it is the same.  I have included the source code for the updater class so you will know what way I am updating the files. By the way this isn't so I can work on it on another computer it is for if I decide to give the game to other people they can get updates without re-downloading the game

```
package com.alan.gfg.utils;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.channels.Channels;
import java.nio.channels.ReadableByteChannel;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

import com.alan.gfg.utils.files.TextFile;

public class Updater {
    private static String currentVersion, newVersion;
    public static int update = 0;

    public static void checkForUpdate(boolean isAuto){
        currentVersion = TextFile.readFile("./version.txt");

        try{
            URL site = new URL("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TehTechGuy1/Twist/master/Twisted%20Dream/version.txt");
            ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(site.openStream());
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("./version.txt");
            fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, 1 << 24);
            fos.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        newVersion = TextFile.readFile("./version.txt");

        if(currentVersion.equals(newVersion)){
            if(!isAuto){
                doNotUpdate();
                return;
            }else{
                Object[] options = 
                    {
                            "Update",
                            "Do Not Update"
                    };

                int temp = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "An update was found for Twisted Dream (Current version: " + currentVersion + " new version: " + newVersion + "Update might take some time\nA window will pop up when it is complete", "Updater", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, options, options[0]);
                if(temp == 1){
                    return;
                } else{
                    TextFile.writeFile("./version.txt", newVersion);

                    try{
                        URL site = new URL("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TehTechGuy1/Twist/master/Twisted%20Dream/res/textures/Player/player.png");
                        ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(site.openStream());
                        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("/textures/Player/player.png");
                        fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, 1 << 24);
                        fos.close();
                    }catch(Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    try{
                        URL site = new URL("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TehTechGuy1/Twist/master/Twisted%20Dream/res/textures/Tiles/hall.png");
                        ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(site.openStream());
                        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("/textures/Tiles/hall.png");
                        fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, 1 << 24);
                        fos.close();
                    }catch(Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    try{
                        URL site = new URL("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TehTechGuy1/Twist/master/Twisted%20Dream/res/textures/Tiles/homeec.png");
                        ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(site.openStream());
                        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("/textures/Tiles/homeec.png");
                        fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, 1 << 24);
                        fos.close();
                    }catch(Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    try{
                        URL site = new URL("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TehTechGuy1/Twist/master/Twisted%20Dream/res/textures/levels/test.png");
                        ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(site.openStream());
                        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("/textures/levels/test.png");
                        fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, 1 << 24);
                        fos.close();
                    }catch(Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    try{
                        URL site = new URL("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TehTechGuy1/Twist/master/Twisted%20Dream/res/settings/config.xml");
                        ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(site.openStream());
                        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("/textures/settings/config.xml");
                        fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, 1 << 24);
                        fos.close();
                    }catch(Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    try{
                        URL site = new URL("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TehTechGuy1/Twist/master/Twisted%20Dream/res/menu/options_b.png");
                        ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(site.openStream());
                        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("/menu/options_b.png");
                        fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, 1 << 24);
                        fos.close();
                    }catch(Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    try{
                        URL site = new URL("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TehTechGuy1/Twist/master/Twisted%20Dream/res/menu/options_b1.png");
                        ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(site.openStream());
                        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("/menu/options_b1.png");
                        fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, 1 << 24);
                        fos.close();
                    }catch(Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    try{
                        URL site = new URL("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TehTechGuy1/Twist/master/Twisted%20Dream/res/menu/play_b.png");
                        ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(site.openStream());
                        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("/menu/play_b.png");
                        fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, 1 << 24);
                        fos.close();
                    }catch(Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    try{
                        URL site = new URL("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TehTechGuy1/Twist/master/Twisted%20Dream/res/menu/play_b1.png");
                        ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(site.openStream());
                        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("/menu/play_b1.png");
                        fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, 1 << 24);
                        fos.close();
                    }catch(Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    try{
                        URL site = new URL("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TehTechGuy1/Twist/master/Twisted%20Dream/res/menu/exit_b.png");
                        ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(site.openStream());
                        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("/menu/exit_b.png");
                        fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, 1 << 24);
                        fos.close();
                    }catch(Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    try{
                        URL site = new URL("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TehTechGuy1/Twist/master/Twisted%20Dream/res/menu/exit_b1.png");
                        ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(site.openStream());
                        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("/menu/exit_b1.png");
                        fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, 1 << 24);
                        fos.close();
                    }catch(Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    try{
                        URL site = new URL("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TehTechGuy1/Twist/master/Twisted%20Dream/res/menu_image.jpg");
                        ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(site.openStream());
                        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("/menu_image.jpg");
                        fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, 1 << 24);
                        fos.close();
                    }catch(Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    finishUpdate();
                    return;
                }
            }


        }
    }

    private static void finishUpdate(){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Game has been updated to" + newVersion + "\nGame will now close", "Update Complete", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        System.exit(0);
    }
    private static void doNotUpdate(){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No update found :(", "Updater", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would try to download an update as an archive type like zip, after that you can unzip these update and run a shell script or something like this and close the old version with the shell script and also open a new one.

If you put it in a jar file it would be much easier, too.

Comment: I am confused, how would I go about doing this